# importing classes from a module in python

Tags: python, class, import, module

If I have a module called Physics with say, 4 classes written in it and I want to make objects with all these classes over in my main file, can I just do:

`import Physics`

or do I need to import each inidivual class by saying:

```
from Physics import ClassA  
from Physics import ClassB`
```

and so on? I ask because I tried to just import the module name, but it would let me instantiate an object from one of the classes.

Comment: You can do both. If there was a problem when you tried to do it, please ask a more specific question.

Comment: You can also do from Physics import * to import everything from the module

Comment: @JadonErwin using `import *` will be a bad idea, a lot of unnecessay thing will be imported this way

Comment: If you just import the module the classes are attributes of that module: `module.Classname()`.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways you can import things. If you plan on using something a lot and names within that module aren't common, you could do

```
from physics import *
```

or

```
from physics import ClassA, ClassB, ClassC
```

When you do this, you do not need to reference the module name when using the names from the module. Example:

```
object = ClassA()
```

If you are only using a few things from a module or the module has things that have common names (like exit() from sys that is like python's exit()) you might consider just importing the whole module so you can tell if it was from the module easily. However, when you do that you have to reference the module name each time you use the thing you want from that module.

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Some module names are longer and it can be annoying to type it out every time you use something from it. Because of that people often save the module imported to a variable:

```
import physics as phy
object = phy.ClassA()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do any if the following:

```
from Physics import ClassA , ClassB
a = ClassA()
b = ClassB()
```

```
import Physics
a = Physics.ClassA()
b = Physics.ClassB()
```

```
from Physics import ClassA  
from Physics import ClassB
a = ClassA()
b = ClassB()
```

```
from Physics import *
a = ClassA()
b = ClassB()
```

Standard conventions usually prefer the first  more than the others due to its conciseness while still being explicit.

Comment: I actually didn't frame my question correctly.  If I have a module called ModuleA with just one class in it, called, say ClassA. Then I have another module called ModuleX with many classes written in it.  For one of the classes in ModuleX I want to initialize one of the instance variables (eg. instVarA) as an object of ClassA.  In ModuleX can I just say import ModuleA and that will allow me to say: self.instVarA = ClassA(w, x, y, z)

Comment: @Tad yes, and the above import statements will work, so long as you don't have cyclical/circular imports (e.g. ModuleX imports from ModuleA, then ModuleA imports from ModuleX as well).

Comment: if I just reference the module name when importing (import ModuleA), wouldn't I have to reference it ahead of naming the class?  i.e. self.instVarA = ModuleA.ClassA(w, x, y, z)?

Comment: Yes, similar to the second example above.